# How to remove xml nodes that are not in an array of xpath strings?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have **an array of xpath values** and **an xml feed**.

When the feed comes in, I want to filter **each xml file** by removing the nodes that are **not in my array of xpath's**.

I can think of a very dirty way to do this:

1) for each node in the xml, i form its xpath

2) check if it's in the array.

3) if not, remove.

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the feed comes in, I want to filter **each xml file** by removing the
>   nodes that are **not in my array of xpath's**

**Step1. Select all nodes that aren't selected by the given XPath expressions**

**I guess that by "nodes" you mean elements.
If so, this XPath expression**:

```
//*[count(. | yourExpr1 | yourExpr2 ... | yourExprN)
   >
    count(yourExpr1 | yourExpr2 ... | yourExprN)
   ]
```

**selects all elements in the XML document that aren't selected by any of your N XPath expressions** `yourExpr1`, `yourExpr2`, ... , `yourExprN`

If by "nodes" you mean elements, text-nodes, processing-instruction-nodes (PIs), comment-nodes and attribute nodes, use this XPath expression to select all nodes not selected by your N XPath expressions:

```
(//node() | //*/@*)
   [count(. | yourExpr1 | yourExpr2 ... | yourExprN)
   >
    count(yourExpr1 | yourExpr2 ... | yourExprN)
   ]
```

**Step2. Delete all nodes selected in Step1.**

For each of the nodes selected in Step1 above, use:

```
 node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

**Explanation**:

1. The XPath union operator `|` produces the union of two node-sets. Therefore the expression `yourExpr1 | yourExpr2 ... | yourExprN` when applied on the XML document produces the set of all nodes that are selected by any of the N given XPath expressions.
2. A node `$n` doesn't belong to a set of nodes `$ns` exactly when 
   ...

   `count($n | $ns) > count($ns)`

Comment: @Lagoona: Sorry -- you cn't. But you still can have a look at my other answers, and it is up to you to upvote the ones you like. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is backwards (and error-prone, since any given node can be selected by multiple valid XPath expressions). You should:

- First, iterate the array of expressions and somehow mark the nodes that each one selects (simply set some flag on each node, for example). Even better: evaluate the union of all the expressions and select everything in one step.
- Then, traverse the DOM and remove any element that wasn't marked in the first step.

Comment: That sounds lovely. 1) other than using an array of xmlnode, is there a native method in xmlnode to mark it? 2) off the top of my head, i can't think of a way to union xpath's...would you give a tip/keyword that will shorten my research time? thanks!

Comment: @Lagoona -  1) I don't know c#, so I can't provide any language-specific support. 2) The union of two expressions is just each of the expressions separated by `|`, like this: `expr1 | expr2 | expr3` (and so on).